# Does a slayer add Strength to the damage from Power Strike?

Tags: dnd-4e

When a Slayer uses his Power Strike feature, it says:

> The target takes 1[W] extra damage from the triggering attack.

Does that extra damage imply that you add your bonus to strength again to the damage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.**

`[W]` is the notation used to indicate the damage die used by your current weapon. Unless explicitly noted, this doesn't include any attribute or other bonuses that are usually applied only once to a damage roll.

For example, if your character had STR 16 and was using a +1 longsword, the attack would deal - ignoring any other factors for the sake of the example -`2d8+4` damage when using *Power Strike* instead of `1d8+4`.